# Data-frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, quandl

Suppose this data.frame is called GC so I want to eliminate columns "Last", "Change" and put it on a new matrix/vector.
Also I want to select the 6th value starting from the end whch date is 1975-02-18.

```
require(Quandl)
GC = Quandl("CME/GCG1975",order = "asc", type="raw")
class(GC)

> class(GC)
[1] "data.frame"

> GC
         Date  Open  High   Low Last Change Settle Volume Prev. Day Open Interest
1  1974-12-31 191.0 191.5 182.7   NA     NA  183.9    512                     237
2  1975-01-02 184.0 184.8 173.9   NA     NA  175.1    294                     209
3  1975-01-03 173.0 175.5 170.5   NA     NA  174.7    174                     216
4  1975-01-06 172.0 174.5 167.5   NA     NA  174.4    197                     225
5  1975-01-07 171.0 174.0 168.5   NA     NA  173.4     98                     240
6  1975-01-08 176.0 180.0 176.0   NA     NA  177.4     69                     224
7  1975-01-09 179.0 179.1 177.0   NA     NA  178.3     25                     246
8  1975-01-10 177.0 181.3 176.5   NA     NA  181.3     24                     260
9  1975-01-13 181.0 181.0 178.6   NA     NA  178.6     31                     258
10 1975-01-14 177.0 178.6 176.5   NA     NA  178.6      7                     255
11 1975-01-15 178.8 179.4 177.3   NA     NA  177.3     29                     275
12 1975-01-16 177.0 177.0 174.6   NA     NA  175.1     40                     266
13 1975-01-17 174.7 174.8 172.1   NA     NA  172.1     18                     296
14 1975-01-20 173.6 176.2 173.6   NA     NA  176.2     18                     268
15 1975-01-21 173.7 173.7 173.7   NA     NA  173.7      0                     277
16 1975-01-22 175.9 175.9 174.3   NA     NA  174.3     38                     285
17 1975-01-23 177.0 177.0 176.4   NA     NA  176.4     40                     290
18 1975-01-24 179.0 180.0 177.8   NA     NA  179.5     55                     325
19 1975-01-27 180.0 180.0 176.8   NA     NA  176.8     30                     320
20 1975-01-28 177.3 177.3 175.4   NA     NA  176.0     93                     340
21 1975-01-29 177.4 179.1 177.4   NA     NA  179.1     12                     336
22 1975-01-30 177.0 177.0 175.8   NA     NA  175.8      8                     336
23 1975-01-31 176.0 176.0 174.7   NA     NA  175.5     33                     338
24 1975-02-03 176.2 176.9 175.8   NA     NA  175.8     25                     336
25 1975-02-04 173.0 174.8 173.0   NA     NA  174.8     10                     331
26 1975-02-05 175.3 175.3 174.2   NA     NA  174.2      5                     331
27 1975-02-06 172.5 173.8 172.1   NA     NA  173.8     20                     157
28 1975-02-07 174.9 175.1 174.9   NA     NA  175.1      2                     154
29 1975-02-10 174.0 174.0 173.7   NA     NA  173.7      3                      80
30 1975-02-11 174.8 174.8 174.8   NA     NA  174.8      0                      77
31 1975-02-13 183.5 183.5 183.5   NA     NA  183.5     52                     103
32 1975-02-14 184.4 184.4 183.1   NA     NA  183.1     12                      79
33 1975-02-18 183.6 183.6 183.6   NA     NA  183.6      0                      59
34 1975-02-19 185.2 185.5 184.0   NA     NA  184.0     11                      58
35 1975-02-20 184.5 186.1 184.5   NA     NA  186.1     18                      72
36 1975-02-21 186.1 186.1 184.5   NA     NA  184.5      5                      72
37 1975-02-24 185.5 185.5 185.5   NA     NA  185.5      0                      69
38 1975-02-25 186.2 186.2 183.1   NA     NA  183.1      5                      19
```

Comment: You already have a lengthy [open question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936334/r-continuous-futures-working-backward) and the current question is very basic `data.frame` operation (sample answer [drop column by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name)). Without familiarity of data.frame, indexing,time series packages(xts,zoo) you face an uphill task, some basic tutorials are [data.frame](https://www.r-bloggers.com/working-with-the-data-frame-in-r/) and [xts](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/01/quantitative-finance-applications-in-r.html)

Comment: thanks Osssan, for your recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question1:

You can select columns from a data frame by doing:

```
select <- GC[,c('Last', 'Change')]
```

If you want to convert it to a matrix you could do:

```
removed_columns <- as.matrix(GC[,c('Last','Change')])
```

You can eliminate these columns from the dataframe by setting them to NULL:

```
GC$Last = GC$Change = NULL
```

Question 2:

You can easily select rows from a dataframe by using a logical operator:

```
value = GC[GC$Date == '1975-02-18',]
```

Did you do a course/tutorial in R? These kind of basic data manipulations are covered in any introductory R course.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks PaulH, Question 1 works for me, and Question 2 it isn't exactly what I want. I want to select the 6th row starting from the last, and the "Date" will change depending on the contract. No I don't and don't want, I find and answer when I need it, thanks for your recommendation. This is a piece of a project: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936334/r-continuous-futures-working-backward] but I have proved that is better to ask multiple simple questions than a complex one.

Comment: SOLVED QUESTION 2: `six_last_row = nrow(GC) - 5` and `GC[six_last_row,]`